# Rabbit MQ AMQP and DaemonKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq, daemon

I am trying to integrate the RabbitMq and AMQP along with the daemon kit to schedule the messaging tasks in Ruby on Rails platform. I am still in the experimental stage. I was referred to few blogs and websites and one of them is:
http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/941/using-daemon-kit-and-robustthread-to-build-ruby-daemons/#evented-daemon

When I tried to run this command:
`daemon-kit -i amqp eventbased` 
inside a Rails app, I got this error:
`No value provided for required arguments 'app_path'`

I am not being able to figure out whats wrong with it. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this error

> No value provided for required arguments 'app_path'

appears cause you should provide path to daemon, like this

```
daemon-kit ~/projects/amqp-dev -i amqp
```

This will generate skeleton daemon in the `amqp-dev` folder.

Im not sure about daemon-kit compatibility with ruby frameworks, like sinatra or rails, but I belive its not really hard to get this work with them.

Comment: Yes that true, I am struggling since a very long time to get this done, and also I am looking for other alternatives too, any heads up?

Comment: So, the first question is do you really need message queueing in your app? Maybe you need just background processing? Please, read this blog post: http://www.mikeperham.com/2011/05/04/background-processing-vs-message-queueing/ I dont know anything about your project, but in most cases things like rabbitMQ or amqp is not really necessary.